# How to get leading zeroes with DatePart?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this piece in my SELECT portion of my TSQL query:

```
CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,s.Arr) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,s.Arr) AS VARCHAR),
```

The original `s.Arr` field looks like:

```
2016-01-04 04:43:00.000
```

The goal is to make it look like:

```
0443
```

But right now my SQL makes it look like:

```
443
```

Because it isn't grabbing the leading zeroes. How can I grab the leading zeroes? Is there a way to do this without hackish methods like padding zeroes onto it?

Server: 2008 R2

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: @Zeno lad2025 is right...only with 2012 or greater can you use format. you are stuck with writing code to pad the zeroes.

Comment: @Jeremy There is also `CONVERT` :) and string operations. But as ugly as padding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `SQL Server 2012+` you can use `FORMAT`:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2016-01-04 04:43:00.000';
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'HHmm');
-- 0443
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/419204)**</kbd>

---

`SQL Server 2008`

Without padding with `0`:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2016-01-04 04:43:00.000';
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @d, 14),5), ':', '');
-- 0443
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/419213)**</kbd>

> Style: **14 hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)**

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, but it looks like the server isn't high enough version `'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: @Zeno See updated. You can avoid padding with 0, but is it worth it? This solution is not readable as FORMAT and need comment.

Answer (score 1):

Padding with 00 and take right two

```
RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,s.Arr) AS VARCHAR),2) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,s.Arr) AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: I am assuming date format will not change.

declare @dt varchar(max) = '2016-01-05 09:42:18.717'

select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(255),@dt),12,len(@dt)-(len(@dt)-2))+SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(255),@dt),15,len(@dt)-(len(@dt)-2))